# Suppress output from a vim autocmd?

Tags: vim

I have a simple `BufWritePost` autocmd to automatically generate HTML from my vimwiki pages.

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.wiki VimwikiAll2HTML
```

But it spits out a lot of progress output, and a prompt at the end:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Is there a way to suppress the output and prompt from a vim autocmd, to make it completely transparent?

Comment: Why not show the command you are executing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add `silent` after the pattern.

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.wiki silent VimwikiAll2HTML
```

And add your `autocmd` that works well to your question, it will greatly help.

Comment: Added the command to the question.  Worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try another option:

```
:h vimwiki-option-auto_export
```

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I wrote the question to be generic (not vimwiki-specific), and it was just coincidental that I used `VimwikiAll2HTML` as an example.  Still, if someone were editing *.wiki files that weren't part of vimwiki, there would be no point in running the HTML conversion on save, so your option is perfect for that scenario.